# postgresql double count query

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table with 3 columns: `key`, `status` and `rank`.
`status` contains numbers and rank contains t or f.
key is auto numbered and irrelevant here.

my goal is to count how many in each status are t and how many false
for example:

if my data is (key, status, rank)

```
1 10 f
2 10 t
3 10 t
4 11 t
```

then result will be : (status, rank, count value)

```
10 f 1
10 t 2
11 t 1
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple [`group by` query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html).

```
select status, 
       rank,
       count(*) as cnt
from the_table
group by status, rank
order by status, rank;
```

Comment: where do you take under consideration the rank? it seems like you just counting statuses regardless of the rank.

Comment: ok based on your answer this is the correct solution: select  
       status, rank,
       count(*) as cnt
from the_table
group by  status, rank
order by status;

Comment: @someone45: ah, sorry. I mixed up the columns.